# Python: Obtain output using subprocess.call, not Popen

Tags: python, subprocess

I have a system call made from a Python script. I would like to have a timer as well as utilizing the output of the call. I was able to do one at a time: Implement a timer using `subprocess.call()` and retrieve the output using `subprocess.Popen()`. However, I need both timer and the output result.

Is there any way to achieve this?

Following code give me an `Attribute error: 'int' object has no attribute 'stdout'`, because the `subprocess.call` output is not the Popen object I need to use.

```
... Open file here ...

try:
    result = subprocess.call(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, timeout=30)
    out = result.stdout.read()
    print (out)
except subprocess.TimeoutExpired as e:
    print ("Timed out!")

... Write to file here ...
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the documentation on `subprocess.call()` the one of the first things I noticed was:

> Note:
>
> Do not use stdout=PIPE or stderr=PIPE with this function. As the pipes are not being read in the current process, the child process may block if it generates enough output to a pipe to fill up the OS pipe buffer.

The next thing was the first line in the documentation

> Run the command described by args. Wait for command to complete, then return the returncode attribute.

`subprocess.call` will return the "exit code", an `int`, generally 0 = success, 1 = something went wrong, etc.

For more infomation on exit codes...http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/exitcodes.html

Since you want the 'output'from your timer, you might want to revert to

```
timer_out = subprocess.Popen(command, shell=True, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE, universal_newlines=True)
stout, sterror = timer_out.communicate()
```

...or something like it.

Comment: do not use `shell=True` unless you need it. OP also can use `subprocess.check_output()`

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian, you're right, my oversight.